# how to write a test for authorization?

Tags: python, django

please help fix the unit test for authorization.

views.py:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect, Http404
from django.template import loader, RequestContext
from django.contrib import auth
from django import forms

def auth_view(request):
    username = request.POST.get('username', '')
    password = request.POST.get('password', '')
    user = auth.authenticate(username=username, password=password)

    if user is not None:
        auth.login(request, user)
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/accounts/loggedin/')
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/accounts/invalid_login/')
```

login.html:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block title %}Login{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    {# {{ form.as_p }} #}

    {% if form.errors %}
        <p>errors!</p>
    {% endif %}

    <form action="/accounts/auth/" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
        <input type="text" name="username" id="isername" value="" />

        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="" />

        <input type="submit" value="login" />
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings

admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('accounts',
    url(r'^login/$', 'views.login'),
    url(r'^auth/$', 'views.auth_view'),
)
```

tests.py:

```
from django.test import TestCase
from django.test.client import Client


class TestLogin(TestCase):
    def test_login(self):
        client = Client()
        response = client.post('/accounts/auth/', {'username': 'qwe', 'password': 'qwe'})
        print(response.content)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 302)
```

I'm doing 2 tests: one for an existing user (username: qwe, password: qwe), 2 for non-existing user (username: qwerty, password: qwe). as a result of the console displays the same [message](http://fh79272k.bget.ru/post.png).

so I did not know was successful or not authorization

Comment: You created the user with that password? Before making the request the user must exist in the test database.

Comment: You're returning exactly the same kind of response for both scenarios. You should either return a different kind of response or test the contents of the `response` object

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume you're testing **authentication** since that's what your code says. Since you return the same HTTP status code both your users pass the assertion in your test. Change `auth_view` method to do this:

```
 if user is not None:
       auth.login(request, user)
       return HttpResponseRedirect('/accounts/loggedin/')
   else:
       return HttpResponseForbidden()
```

So when you do this:

```
self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 302)
```

it will only pass for existing users.